# xamarin forms bindable property does not work properly

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, bindableproperty

i am trying to create custom view like below
here i am trying to bind a collection from main page to custom view

but here it is not binding properly.

```
<ContentView.Content>
        <Grid
            x:Name="Layout"
            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
            VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">

            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <StackLayout
                Grid.Row="0"
                BackgroundColor="#E0E0E0"
                Padding="20,10">
                <Label Text="{Binding Source={x:Reference ExpandableContentView}, Path=Header}"/>
            </StackLayout>

            <StackLayout
                Grid.Row="1"
                BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Reference ExpandableContentView}, Path=SummeryList}">

                <Label Text="{Binding Test}"/>
            </StackLayout>

        </Grid>
    </ContentView.Content>
```

**xmal.cs file**

```
public partial class ExpandableView : ContentView
    {
        public static readonly BindableProperty HeaderProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
            nameof(Header),
            typeof(string),
            typeof(ExpandableView),
            default(string));

        public static readonly BindableProperty SummeryListProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
            nameof(SummeryList),
            typeof(ObservableCollection<SummeryDetailModel>),
            typeof(ExpandableView),
            propertyChanged: CollectionChanged);

        private static void CollectionChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
        {
        }

        public ExpandableView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public string Header
        {
            get => (string)GetValue(HeaderProperty);
            set => SetValue(HeaderProperty, value);
        }

        public ObservableCollection<SummeryDetailModel> SummeryList
        {
            get => (ObservableCollection<SummeryDetailModel>)GetValue(SummeryListProperty);
            set => SetValue(SummeryListProperty, value);
        }
```

i am doing the binding in MainPage like below

```
<commonviews:ExpandableView
            Header="Shipment Details"
            SummeryList="{Binding SummeryCollection}">
        </commonviews:ExpandableView>
```

My **SummeryDetailModel** like

```
public class SummeryDetailModel
    {
        public string Test { get; set; }
    }
```

here it is not binding the **Test** value to label.

anything i missed here?

Comment: I assume because the list doesn’t have such a property, the elements inside it do. But you’re binding to the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just figure out this, there was a small mistake that i have done.

i did not add **Itemtemplate**  **DataTemplate** for **StackLayout** **BindableLayout**

it is as follows

```
<StackLayout
                Grid.Row="1"
                Padding="20,10"
                Spacing="15"
                BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Reference ExpandableContentView}, Path=SummeryList}">
                <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackLayout
                            Spacing="10">
                            <Label
                                Text="{Binding Title}"
                                FontFamily="{StaticResource LatoRegular}"
                                FontSize="{StaticResource FontSize14}"
                                TextColor="{StaticResource PlaceholderColor}"/>

                            <Label Text="{Binding Detail}"
                                   FontFamily="{StaticResource LatoRegular}"
                                   FontSize="{StaticResource FontSize14}"
                                   TextColor="{StaticResource PrimaryText}"/>

                        </StackLayout>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
            </StackLayout>
```